# How to access timings of each individual test in a TestReport?

Tags: testing-and-verification

I want to know how long each VerificationTest took to complete in the test report, so see which one was the longest and do some statistics on them:

```
TestReport[
 Table[VerificationTest[
   FullSimplify[2 Sin[12 x + 15 y] Cos[14 x + 21 y]], 
   Simplify[2 Sin[12 x + 15 y] Cos[14 x + 21 y]]], {10}]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most straightforward method seems to be to map the test property you are looking for over the `TestReportObject`, as follows:

```
report = TestReport[{VerificationTest[Limit[Exp[t], t -> 0], 2], 
  VerificationTest[PrimeQ[7]],
  VerificationTest[Factor[1 - 2 x + x^2], (x + 1)^2],
  VerificationTest[Infinity - Infinity, Indeterminate]}];

Map[#["AbsoluteTimeUsed"] &]@report["TestResults"]
(* 
 <|1 -> Quantity[0.029815, "Seconds"], 
   2 -> Quantity[0.000135, "Seconds"], 
   3 -> Quantity[0.000217, "Seconds"], 
   4 -> Quantity[0.001597, "Seconds"]|>
*)
```

---

An alternative, is to use `Query`:

```
Query[All, (#["AbsoluteTimeUsed"] &)]@report["TestResults"]
```

which produces identical results. It is more verbose than `Map`, but it is potentially cleaner.

---

The cleanest method, as pointed out by Ilian, is to use `Through`, e.g.

```
Through[Values[report["TestResults"]]["AbsoluteTimeUsed"]]
```

even though it is not the shortest character wise.

Comment: I concur that this is the best way to do this.

Comment: The #[]&/@ syntax isn't the prettiest.

Comment: It's not, but I found one with `Query`. Will add it.

Comment: For just the timings (and prettier syntax), maybe `Through[Values[report["TestResults"]]["AbsoluteTimeUsed"]]`.